# Objects in an array contain a specific value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to build a Blackjack game in Javascript and wanting to determine if the Player's hand contains an "Ace".

I have an array for the Player's hand and Dealer's hand to contain all the cards, each card object has 3 values associated with it...the cards name, suit and value.  How do you look specifically for the value "Ace" for each object in the array?

```
function card(name, suit, value) {
    this.name = name;
    this.suit = suit;
    this.value = value;
}

var playerHand = [];

var drawOne = function() {
   var card = cardsInDeck.pop();
   return card;
}

var p1 = drawOne();
    playerHand.push(p1.value);
var p2 = drawOne();
    playerHand.push(p2.value);

    if ((playerHand.indexOf("Ace") > 0) && playerTotal > 21) {
        playerTotal -= 10;
    }
```

Any insight into how to approach this correctly would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share the structure of `playerHand` object

Comment: Sorry, just updated with a bit more of the structure of how the hands are built in it.

Comment: Can you also share the card's structure?

Comment: So, think I'm just not using my head right...I'm populating the array with the value of the card, and not the name...I needed to look for the indexOf the Aces "value" and not the "name".  Adjusted my code and it works properly now.

Comment: Cool, so never pushed the whole card to playerHand, only its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have an array for the Player's hand and Dealer's hand to contain all
>   the cards, each card object has 3 values associated with it.

Assuming `playerHand` is an array, you can try

```
var hasAce = playerHand.some( function( card ){
  return card.suite.toLowerCase() == "ace";  
});
```

Now just proceed with your rest of the logic

```
if ( hasAce && playerTotal > 21) {
    playerTotal -= 10;
}
```

**Edit**

Based on the updates shared by you, since you are only pushing the value rather than the object, `indexOf` will work just fine

```
if ((playerHand.indexOf("Ace") > 0) && playerTotal > 21) {
    playerTotal -= 10;
}
```